# Jackson - Serializing a value only if a condition met, ignore nulls

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

I'm trying to serialize a Java POJO and omit certain fields if some condition was not met.

The solution that I have so far looks like following:

```
public class PermissionSerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> implements ContextualSerializer {

    private String role;

    public PermissionSerializer() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    public PermissionSerializer(String role) {
        super(Object.class);
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        String curRole = SomeContext.getCurrentRole();


        if (curRole.equals(role)) {
            jgen.writeObject(value);
            return;
        }
        jgen.writeNull();
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        String unit = null;
        AllowedFor ann = null;
        if (property != null) {
            ann = property.getAnnotation(AllowedFor.class);
        }
        if (ann != null) {
            unit = ann.role();
        }
        return new PermissionSerializer(unit);
    }
}
```

Then in the POJO I'm using it like:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = PermissionSerializer.class)
@AllowedFor(role = "admin")
private String advancedField;
```

It actually works, except that it might be not the nicest way of achieving what I want.
However, there is another problem with this approach. If we don't have permissions to show the field, it is serialized as `null` in the resulting JSON, even if I have `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` on the class level.

Is it possible to actually ignore this field completely? Or maybe there is a better way conditionally ignore fields?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a [ResponseAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html) for decorating the response based on the authentication level.

First of all `JsonIgnore` on the field you don't want to show, not even the key even if the value is `null`.

```
@JsonIgnore
private String advancedField;
```

Now, set up the the `ResponseAdvice`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyResponseBodyAdvisor implements ResponseBodyAdvice<String> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return returnType.getDeclaringClass().equals(MyClass.class) && converterType.equals(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String beforeBodyWrite(String body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});

        String currentRole = SomeContext.getCurrentRole();
        if(currentRole.equals(Roles.SomeRole)) {
           map.put("advancedField", "advancedValue");
        }

        return mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
    }
}
```

Pretty much that is all you have to do. The advantage of using this approach is that you are binded to the `Spring` eco-system with this approach and can use all the goodies that it provides if you need Dependency Injection and all that. Also, its cleaner than using validation logic in the `Serializer`. You should look into [ResponseAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html) if you need better support to your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Whereas it looks like it may work, unfortunately, i don't use Spring Boot. Also for me it looks cleaner if I could achieve this task with native Jackson possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a Custom Filter and add it to you ObjectMapper instance. Assuming you want to do more complex things than just check if a value is null or not then you could create a custom filter which uses something like an expression in an annotation on the property you want to conditionally serialize.

I built something similar recently - https://github.com/johnhunsley/conditional-jackson-property-filter